# flutter + protobuf + (some encryption algorithm), is this OK?

Tags: flutter, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

flutter + protobuf + (some encryption algorithm), is this OK?
do i need to add (some encryption algorithm) for my app while using protobuf?
is it able to use protobuf with flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a great question, you might want to narrow it down a bunch to specific issues you need to resolve.

Answer:

- Flutter + protobuf work together just fine. protoc will compile the Dart code and you can run with that.
- Encryption is an unrelated topic. How you handle it depends on what you need. You can encrypt the protobuf contents if you need to, or not.
- If you are sending/receiving buffers over the network, then you can use HTTPS to encrypt the data on the wire.

Summary: Lots of tutorials will cover everything you need to learn about this.

Comment: thank you. so if the App is over the internet, is it nessesary to encrypt the protobuf, right? is it able to encrypt the protobuf by HTTPS?

Comment: HTTPS is encrypted, so depending on your needs, you may not need to encrypt the protobufs separately. I'd suggest you consider what you are trying to protect against. I can see cases where encrypting the payloads even over HTTPS might make sense. Or cases where they need to be digitally signed. Or both. It depends on what you are trying to protect against.

Comment: take facebook or twitter for example, username and password of course need to be encrypted, but is it nessesarry to encrypt all, including chat content, every twit, friend list and status.